# Installing private npmjs packages fail when yarn.lock is present

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a project that depends on some packages that are published to a **private [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/) account**. For example, `@myaccount/first-package`.

I have a project level `.npmrc` file that has following configuration,

```
@myaccount:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=npm_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
always-auth=true
```

> Auth token used here is generated from npmjs web, and it is a classic token. I have tried with both readonly token and publish (read+publish) token.

Yarn config seem to be loading the proper configuration as well. Following is the output of `yarn config list`,

```
yarn config v1.22.19
info yarn config
{
  'version-tag-prefix': 'v',
  'version-git-tag': true,
  'version-commit-hooks': true,
  'version-git-sign': false,
  'version-git-message': 'v%s',
  'init-version': '1.0.0',
  'init-license': 'MIT',
  'save-prefix': '^',
  'bin-links': true,
  'ignore-scripts': false,
  'ignore-optional': false,
  registry: 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com',
  'strict-ssl': true,
  'user-agent': 'yarn/1.22.19 npm/? node/v18.17.1 linux x64',
  lastUpdateCheck: 1693395311360
}
info npm config
{
  '@myaccount:registry': 'https://registry.npmjs.org/',
  '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken': 'npm_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'always-auth': true
}
```

With this setup, when I run `yarn install` for the first time where `yarn.lock` does not have an entry for `@myaccount/first-package` or `yarn.lock` file does not exist, it is properly installing the package to node_modules and adds the following entry to the `yarn.lock`.

```
"@myaccount/first-package@^0.2.36":
  version "0.2.36"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myaccount/first-package/-/first-package-0.2.36.tgz#340c2c976497bad20d7552e52608ac8d5355e2ab"
  integrity sha512-45dk+EpASIHs8g+bC+DPD/VeZIbDbL74xJ4viIj+K9Sx0Qv3M8I/EoXvTG1zHxmz/7Itt5AmpwH7/vxlop26IQ==
```

But, once I delete node_modules and re-run `yarn install` or someone else (both developers and cicd docker client) checks out the code that has the new `yarn.lock` and run `yarn install`, they are getting a 404 error as follows,

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myaccount/first-package/-/first-package-0.2.36.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
```

But, once they delete `yarn.lock` and run `yarn install` they are able to install packages without any issues.

A verbose output of install command (`yarn install --verbose`) rendered following,

Success scenario:

```
verbose 3.066711833 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.npmjs.org/@myaccount%2ffirst-package".
verbose 3.809710167 Request "https://registry.npmjs.org/@myaccount%2ffirst-package" finished with status code 200.
```

Fail scenario:

```
verbose 1.960352751 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myaccount/first-package/-/first-package-0.2.36.tgz".
verbose 5.081442544 Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myaccount/first-package/-/first-package-0.2.36.tgz: Request failed "404 Not Found"
```

What is the reason for this behaviour and how to fix it?

I am using,

```
Node.js v18.17.1
npm     v8.19.2
yarn    v1.22.19
```

FEW MORE NOTES:

- Requesting same failed URL with Postman with authentication bearer token retunred 200.
- Using npm instead of yarn does not cause this issue. But, I cannot change the package manager.
- Issue remained the same when `.npmrc` file was global (`~/.npmrc`).
- Deleting `yarn.lock` is not an option as I am highly dependant on it for cicd pipeline.
- In this case, I am adding packages to `package.json` manually and then running `yarn install` later due to some other housekeeping work in the project.

Comment: Do you have a `yarnrc` file? If yes, can you share that?

Comment: There is no yarnrc file

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by running the below commands in your terminal:

```
$ yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
$ rm yarn.lock
$ yarn
```

The above steps will regenerate your `yarn.lock` file, and add the npm registry to your yarn config.

Comment: Running this command also fails with "Not found". Slightly different log - `error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/@myaccount%2ffirst-package: Not found".` Tried this url with authentication bearer token in Postman and it is returning OK 200 with data.

Comment: @charith.arumapperuma have updated my answer. Can you check again?

Comment: I tried that. But still getting the same error as in previous comment. Running `yarn config get npmAuthToken` and `yarn config get registry` returning proper values.

Comment: Can you share the output of `yarn config get registry`?

Comment: `yarn config get registry` retunrs "https://registry.npmjs.org/" (without quotes)

Comment: @charith.arumapperuma Are you setting the correct `npmAuthToken` token? Not seeing any issue besides that.

Comment: Isn't `npmAuthToken` for yarn 2.x? I'm using v1.22.19

Comment: @charith.arumapperuma Can you try without setting the `npmAuthToken` (since you are using v1)?